# Proving $(A\cup \bar{B})\cap B = A \cap B$

Tags: set-theory

**Method $1$:** I am getting $(A\cup \bar{B})\cap B=\phi$, when I use Venn diagram of $A\cup\bar{B}$ and $B$ and then take intersection of these two sets.

[image]

**Method $2$:** But when I use set theory manipulations, I have $$(A\cup\bar{B})\cap B=(A\cap B)\cup(\bar{B}\cap B)=A\cap B$$

I don't know why I am getting different results.

Please help me clear my doubt.

Comment: Would you please include the Venn diagram you're referring to in the post? By inspection, Method 2 seems to provide the correct result.

Comment: @allegro.sostenuto I've added an Image for the same

Comment: Venn is wrong - take full A when joining with $\bar{B}$

Comment: What does $n$ mean, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson $n(A)$ Denotes number of elements in set $A$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that in your Venn diagram for $(A\cup\bar{B})$, you did not include $(A\cap{B})$ which should be in $A$ by definition.

Adjusting your Venn diagram, $(A\cup\bar{B})$ should look like:
[image]
which demonstrates $(A\cup\bar{B})\cap B=A\cap B$ as desired.